# innerHTML removed when angularjs reloads the ngView

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-routing

**EDIT**
If I put the data into a global object, I can check the global object for content.  If the global object already has data, kill the function, don't run another AJAX request and inject HTML from the global object into the page.  Using `$scope` or `$http` does't seem to solve the problem.  If anyone has a better solution, I'd be glad to know it.

This is how I want it to work, but that plunker doesn't have page routing:

[plunker - inject HTML into two different pages. Content saved in $scope](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mkpf2e?p=preview)

My website has a page named STORES. When the user clicks the STORES menu, and the STORES page is loaded, AJAX gets all the store names, and puts all the store names into the STORES page.  The HTML for the store names is added with `innerHTML`.  That injected HTML of store names seems to be lost every time angularjs loads the template again.  I have code that runs every time the STORES page is loaded.  That code checks for whether the UL tag with all the store names has any childNodes, and if the value is zero, then the store names are added.  Every time that I navigate to the STORES page, and angularjs loads the page, the UL tag has no child nodes.  (All the store names are gone.)  I want to be able to retrieve the store names and inject the HTML content just once, and not need to run it again.

- User clicks the STORES menu item
- URL is changed
- angularjs detects a URL change
- angularjs route loads a templateURL
- A ng-controller in the HTML page triggers because it is in an HTML element
- The code checks for whether there are any store names in the page.
- If no store names, the controller runs AJAX to get data
- The data is injected as HTML into the UL element

Everything works.  The code is not broken.  The code doesn't have any errors in it.  I just want a way to keep whatever HTML was injected from being lost every time angularjs reloads the page.

### HTML

```
<ul id='storesCat'></ul>
```

The above UL element receives the HTML.  The element below holds the UL tag.

```
<section ng-controller="HideShowInStores">
  <ul id='storesCat'></ul>
</section>
```

When angularjs routes to the page, the controller "HideShowInStores" triggers some code to run.

```
if (elStoreList.childNodes.length === 0) {
  console.log('there are NO child nodes: ');
  .....  Code left out here for sake of condensing the code
  htmlToInject = xmlhttp.responseText;

  elStoreList.innerHTML=htmlToInject;
};
```

### $routeProvider

```
function($routeProvider) {    
  $routeProvider.
    when('/Stores', {
      templateUrl: 'Client_Pages/HTML/Stores.html'
}).
```

When the user clicks the STORES menu, the URL gets changed, the router runs, and puts the Stores.html page into the ng-View DIV, then more HTML is put into the unordered list tag.  Whatever HTML was put into the UL tag, seems to be lost every time the user navigates to another page.

Is there a way I can get angularjs to maintain that HTML that was injected?

Comment: Did you tried to put the text on an $scope variable?

Comment: why aren't you loading the html  through angular methods `$http` and binding it with scope methods?

Comment: Okay, I guess I need to be using $http.  [Documentation $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)